# How to download jasper report automatically from website when startup computer

Tags: java, jasper-reports, client

My scenario is I need to open up the browser, log in to a website, generate and download the PDF jasperreport-built report everyday. Can I create a client script in my local computer to do all these automatically in background so that when I start up my computer, it will pop up the report automatically for me. How can I achieve this? Any expert advice is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st. Create a Java Servlet.
like below.

```
public class JasperExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            JasperReport report = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject("Your Jasper Path");
            Map parameters = new HashMap();
            parameters.put("foo", someParam1);
            parameters.put("bar", someParam2);

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("Your DB Info");
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,parameters,con);

            // Output PDF to HTTP Response
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, response.getOutputStream());
        } catch ( Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jasperexample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.package.JasperExampleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jasperexample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jasperexample</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

2nd. Test your servlet.
Type a URL in your browser.
http://yourserver:port/context/jasperexample

3rd. Create a batch file to open a browser with URL.
start http://yourserver:port/context/jasperexample

4th. Run that Batch file at startup.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. I will try it out first. Anyway, how do I bypass the login authentication for the website?

Comment: Can I reuse the existing java program to generate the report without creating the new Java Servlet?

Comment: What you need is processing request and response pdf.

Comment: You mean I still need to modify the existing program to accept http request and response parameters? Is there any other way? Thanks.

Comment: The existing program has parameters to generate the report (something like logged-in user code), isn't it?
You should modify existing program to generate the pdf, and somehow to download it.
window.open()? redirect?